# How to handle an invalid content type in Rest Template?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, http, mime-types, resttemplate

I am querying a REST API, for negative cases in response I am getting a 200 code and some weird Content-type in headers. Because of this I am unable to store the response, as it throws an exception while parsing.

Below image shows the headers from the response:

[image: Headers: content-type | screenshot]
 [image: Response body | screenshot]

ResponseErrorHandler:

```
@Component
public class AutomationResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AutomationResponseErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        logger.error("Response Error: {} {} {}", response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusText(), response.getBody());   
    }
}
```

Custom RestTemplate:

```
@Component
public class CustomRestTemplate {

    @Autowired
    AutomationResponseErrorHandler responseErrorHandler;

    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(boolean isHttpsRequired)
            throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {

        // if https is not required,
        if (!isHttpsRequired) {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }

        // else below code adds key ignoring logic for https calls
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                .build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(responseErrorHandler);

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Below is the code for saving response:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(outBound, String.class);
```

Below is the Exception occured:

```
at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:534)
at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:869)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:725)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:359)
at com.att.aotsm.msnautomationscheduler.TicketCloseAutomation.queryTicketCloseAPI(TicketCloseAutomation.java:54)
at com.att.aotsm.msnautomationscheduler.AutomationInvokeWebService.queryTicketCloseAPI(AutomationInvokeWebService.java:71)
at com.att.aotsm.msnautomationscheduler.AutomationThreadProcess.run(AutomationThreadProcess.java:138)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "`colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("MSN/Port", "Count"))": does not contain '/'
at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.java:194)
at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:531)
... 12 more
```

I want the to save the response body, no matter whatever the content-type is.

Comment: Can you edit to add the exception you receive?

Comment: Hi @Sterconium, I have updated the description with the exception body.